# RVM list - Warning! PATH is not properly set up

Tags: ruby, rvm

I know this has been asked many times before, however i've tried lots of suggestions to get my ruby working, but nothings worked so far.

When running rvm list, i get:

```
 Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/tom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin' is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for 'PATH=...' entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles'.
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.4.1'.
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.0.0-p648 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

.bashrc:

```
  # Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Nothing related in .bash_profile

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this `rvm reset`
Then run: `rvm version`

Let me Know if it still not resolved
Thanks!

Comment: Im trying to install 1.9.3 however i get this error in the log:  Error: homebrew/versions was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.

Comment: TRy this 
`brew remove gcc49` ,
`rvm get branch /drop-homebrew-versions` , 
`rvm requirements`
and accept ans and upvote if it fixed your issue

Comment: Sorry, so `brew remove gcc49 = Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc@4.9`, `rvm get branch /drop-homebrew-versions = Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/drop-homebrew-versions.tar.gz
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found`, `rvm requirements = Error: homebrew/versions was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.`

Comment: Trying to update my ruby version using rvm, then this error comes up. But the fix works thanks @rahulmishra